# how to use multiple gradients with TensorFlow GradientTape?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, gradient

Having 3 neural networks connected as in the below code, how can we take two gradients from the initial network? The first gradient works but the second one returns `None` tensor. It seems like they are not related to each other to get the gradient. How can I solve this problem?

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape1:
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape2:
        output1 = NN_model1(input1, training=True)
        output2 = NN_model2(output1, training=True)
        output3 = NN_model3([input1, output1, output2], training=True)
        loss1 = -tf.math.reduce_mean(output3)
        loss2 = -tf.math.reduce_mean(output2)
    grad1 = tape2.gradient(loss1, NN_model1.trainable_variables)
grad2 = tape1.gradient(loss2, grad1)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad2, NN_model1.trainable_variables))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think correct approach should be as follows:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    output1 = NN_model1(input1, training=True)
    output2 = NN_model2(output1, training=True)
    output3 = NN_model3([input1, output1, output2], training=True)
    loss1 = -tf.math.reduce_mean(output3)
    loss2 = -tf.math.reduce_mean(output2)
grad = tape.gradient([loss1, loss2], NN_model1.trainable_variables)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grad, NN_model1.trainable_variables))
```